# How do I trigger the notification daily in the background

Tags: android, service, triggers, notifications, alarmmanager

Im struggling make the notification work in my app. I was able to set a button onclicklistener to trigger the notification but now I want to set up automatic notification everday at 3pm. Question is where should I put the notification code and alarmmanager code? since Im not using the button trigger anymore. Also, is there a simple way to make it run in the background like Service so even when the app isn't open, it will automatically remind the user by firing notification everyday at a specific time?  Thanks

**Notification**

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GFXSurface.class);
    PendingIntent pi2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    String body = "This is a message from the Health Effect";
    String title = "The Health Effect";
    Notification n = new Notification(R.drawable.notification, body,
            System.currentTimeMillis());
    n.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, body, pi2);
    n.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
    nm.notify(uniqueID, n);
    finish();
```

**Alarm Tigger**

```
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) this
            .getSystemService(this.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, new Intent(this,
            StatusBar.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```